# jquery doesn't work in my asp.net content page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a master page Like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="../Styles/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div id="Page">
         <div id="divMaster" style="width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid red;" 
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </div>

     <script>
    $("#divMaster").click(function () { alert("div in Master Page has been clicked);});
   </script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my content page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="serve
   <div id="divContent" style="width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid red;" runat="server"></div>
    <script>
    $("#divContent").click(function () { alert("div in content page has been clicked);});
   </script>
</asp:Content
```

in Master page showing and hiding div works but in content page not work.
My question?

why jquery (showing and hiding div )doesn't work in my content page?

Comment: You need to show you jQuery functions.

Comment: for example i show and hide one div in master page with jquery but when i do same work on my content page it doesn't work !

Comment: You need to include Jquery in your content page as like of master page to work your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hold your js code in a separte file, lets say `script.js`

In your master page:

```
 <script src="path/to/script.js"></script>
```

In your js file (script.js):

```
$(document).on('event', '#element', function() {
   // your code here ..
});
```

The `on()` function will identify any element with id `element`, even if this element is loaded dynamicaly after page load

**EDIT**

You just have to include (in your master page only), first the jquery file and then your script.js file

Your code in a separate file:

```
$(document).click(
        function () {
            $("#KadreNemayeshePayam").hide(1);
        }
        );

    $(document).on('click', '#DivPayamha', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var knp = $("#KadreNemayeshePayam"); 
        if (knp.is(":hidden")) {
            knp.show(1);
            ListePayamhaRaBegir();
        }
        else {
            knp.hide(500);
        }

    });
    function ListePayamhaRaBegir()
    {
        var vizhegiha = {};
        vizhegiha.url="/Modiriat/Modiriat.Master/GetMessages";
        vizhegiha.type = "POST";
        vizhegiha.data = null;
        vizhegiha.contentType = "application/json/:charset:utf-8";
        vizhegiha, datatype = "json";
        vizhegiha.success = function (data) { $('lvPayam').bind(data); };
        vizhegiha.error = function () { };
        $.ajax(vizhegiha);
    }
    //===========================           ===============
    $(document).on('click', '#KadreNemayeshePayam', function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
    //===========================  ===============
    $(document).on('click', '#NavarAbzar', function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

**NOTE**

In this line:

```
vizhegiha.success = function (data) { $('lvPayam').bind(data); };
```

lvPayam is not a valid html tag, so it should be `$('#lvPayam')` or `$('.lvPayam')`

Comment: do you khow why my jquery doesn't work in my content page?should i add ref and ... on my content page?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous answer i must say that your element's ID will in case this is a server control (runat="server" attribute is seted) be probably the dynamic. So you should use `'#'+'<%=lvPayam.ClientID%>'` as the Id.

Answer (score 1):

Because of runat="server" it is not working.

Use

```
 <div id="divContent" style="width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid red;"></div>
```